# Need help moving from Net/LDAP to Devise/LDAP in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ldap

I have a Rails 3 app using [net-ldap](https://github.com/ruby-ldap/ruby-net-ldap), which I'm upgrading to Rails 4 using [devise_ldap_authenticatable](https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable).

Previously, I had a helper class which authenticated the user with the domain. This was done without any admin access. Here's the snippet:

```
class LDAPHelper

  def authenticate(host, port, domain)
    @ldap      = Net::LDAP.new
    @ldap.host = host
    @ldap.port = port
    @ldap.auth "#{domain}\\#{@login}", @password
    @authenticated = @ldap.bind
  end

end
```

The above snippet works fine in my Rails 3 app.  Now, in the new Rails 4 app, using devise it's not finding the user, then getting an error it's not authenticated:

```
LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: cn=myuser
LDAP: LDAP search for login: cn=myuser
LDAP: LDAP search yielded 0 matches
LDAP: Authorizing user cn=myuser,etc...
LDAP: Not authorized because not authenticated.
```

I've tried switching the attribute from `cn` to `sAMAccountName`, however, that didn't seem to have any effect.

I'm wondering if it has to do with the fact that I need to somehow pass in the `domain` like I was before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  I added this to `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
config.ldap_auth_username_builder = Proc.new() {|attribute, login, ldap| "MYDOMAIN\\#{login}"}
```